# How to specify myIP in CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

When I create a security group via the console, I can define it as myIP. This is keeps my ingress connection secure and it is very handy. Now when I create a new security group using CloudFormation yml files, how do I specify that? Probably, it needs an external script that grabs the current IP and uses that. Is there an easy way to do that? I do not see that in AWS documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-security-group-ingress.html)

Comment: You can use a service such as https://api.ipify.org to get your IP address (`curl https://api.ipify.org`) and then supply that as an input parameter to your stack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are triggering the stack creation from your computer, you can create a shell script to find your ip address and trigger the cloudformation stack creation.

something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

myIp=$(curl ifconfig.co)
aws cloudformation create-stack \
   --stack-name myteststack \
   --template-body file://sampletemplate.json \
   --parameters ParameterKey=MyIpAddress,ParameterValue=$myIp
```

But this is not ideal if you create your stack from an automation machine, because the ip address will be the automation machine's ip address.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Something similar to this is what we ended up doing. +1 for bringing up the issue of automation machine in using "myIp".